# OpenCV 3.1.0 cross compile error under codesourcery ARM toolchain

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, codesourcery

To compile opencv 3.1.0 for arm v9, I used cross compile codesourcery under Ubuntu
The verion of arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc is "gcc version 4.6.1 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2011.09-50)"

Refering to , I tried two different cmake file to configure

cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv-3.1.0/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../opencv-3.1.0

cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake ../opencv-3.1.0

These two will result the following error:

```
linuxuser@linuxuser:~/build$ make
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  7%] Built target libtiff
[ 12%] Built target libjpeg
[ 17%] Built target libwebp
[ 20%] Built target libjasper
[ 20%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 20%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/split.cpp.o
/home/linuxuser/nfs/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/split.cpp: In function 'void cv::hal::split8u(const uchar*, uchar**, int, int)':
/home/linuxuser/nfs/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/split.cpp:408:1: internal compiler error: in neon_disambiguate_copy, at config/arm/arm.c:20874
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://support.codesourcery.com/GNUToolchain/> for instructions.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/split.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could someone help me to solve this? 
Many thanks

EDITS,

After used new version (2013) of codesourcery, I can compile 3.1.0 now. Thanks

Comment: Not much to say here - there's a bug in the compiler, and it's even had the good grace to tell you itself. Maybe don't use an obsolete compiler version that predates the code you're trying to build by nearly half a decade?

Comment: It's said new version of codesourcery is not free. so...

Comment: Some Lite toolchains were discontinued, but the Xilinx Lite release continued for some time after 2011. The last release was 2015.05. https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/release3049 (registration required, but you should already have done that).